# how to track if user is scrolling up from the bottom of the page?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I am working on a page, and trying to figure out , if user scrolls to a certain threshold on the page and then scrolled back up.

js

```
$(window).scroll(() =>  {
   

});
```

css

```
#header {
  height:50px; 
  width:100%
}

#container{

}

#header {
  height:50px; 
}
```

html page

```
<html>
   <head>
      <title>Title</title>
   </head>
   <body>
      <div id='header'>Header</div>
      <div id='container'> </div>
      <div id='footer'></div>
   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You need to store `scrollTop` value somewhere. Then on next scroll event you can compare it with previously stored value. If it's bigger - user is scrolling down, if it's smaller - user is scrolling up.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onscroll

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in this example, you catch two events at once - `top` and `bottom`.

```js
function scrollDetect(){
  var lastScroll = 0;

  window.onscroll = function() {
      let currentScroll = document.documentElement.scrollTop || document.body.scrollTop;

      if (currentScroll > 0 && lastScroll <= currentScroll){
        lastScroll = currentScroll;
        console.log('bottom');
      }else{
        lastScroll = currentScroll;
        console.log('top');
      }
  };
}


scrollDetect();
```

```css
#header {
  height:50px; 
  width:100%
}

#container{
  height: 5000px;
}

#header {
  height:50px; 
}
```

```html
<html>
   <head>
      <title>Title</title>
   </head>
   <body>
      <div id='header'>Header</div>
      <div id='container'> </div>
      <div id='footer'></div>
   </body>
</html>
```